# Roots of irreducible polynomial over finite field

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials

I have this, and a couple other problems of this kind:

> For $\mathbb{F}_9=\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2+1)$, what are the roots of $z^2+1\in\mathbb{F}_9[z]$?

I can't figure out, how to start with the solution. Can somebody please guide me through the solution of this problem and/or provide some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The roots are the elements $\pm x + (x^{2} + 1)$ of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Let us verify, by substituting $x + (x^{2} + 1)$ in place of $z$ in $z^{2} + 1$. We have
$$
(x + (x^{2} + 1))^{2} + 1 = x^{2} + 1 + (x^{2} + 1) = 0 + (x^{2} + 1).
$$

More generally, if $f(x) \in F[x]$ is a (monic, say) irreducible polynomial over the field $F$, then $E = F[x] / (f(x))$ is a field, and $E$ contains a root of $f(z) \in E[z]$, and such a root is $x + (f(x))$.

Answer (score 0):

The filed $\mathbb F_9$ can be described so:
$$\{0,1,2,x,2x,x+1,x+2,2x+1,2x+2\}$$
and stablishing that $x^2=2$.

The squares of these elements are
$$\{0,1,1,2,2,2x,2x,x+2,2x+2\}$$

So the solutions are $x$ and $2x$.

Comment: How exactly did you get the $\{0,1,2,x,2x,x+1,x+2,2x+1,2x+2\}$? (in more generally described steps/reason)